# Unable to get USB 3.0 working in VMWare Guest Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player, usb-3

I am having a tough time in getting USB 3 work with VMWare Player 12 on Windows 7.

Host – Gigabyte 880GM USB3 board with Etron USB 3 controller. AMD Athlon CPU, 12GB RAM, Windows 7 64

Guest – VMWare Player 12, Windows 7 64, 4GB RAM, USB 3 enabled in VM configuration and successfully installed the recommended  Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver_5.0.3.42 in Guest Windows 7

The issue is when I connect a USB 2 or USB 3 pen drive at Host USB 3 port it is just not detected in the VM at all. Only once it mysteriously appeared but when I tried to connect it gave ‘Host is using the device’ error, but then no files or even explorer window was open on host.

I even tried installing the Etron drivers in Guest but it fails.
I think there’s some incompatibility between the Etron Host device and the Intel USB 3 controller driver. There’s no issue with USB 2 ports at all.
What else can I try?

Comment: See if the following article applies also to VMWare Player : [USB 3.0 support for Windows 7 virtual machine in VMware Workstation and VMware Fusion (2128105)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2128105).

Comment: Thanks for the link @harrymc. I have followed the same procedure as mentioned in the link. USB 3.0 is enabled for the VM. The same specified drivers from Intel are installed and I do see USB 3 devices under Device Manager in Guest Windows 7 OS however USB devices plugged in at the Host USB 3.0 port are not detected by VM at all.

Comment: Is the guest VM defined with VMWare Workstation 12 compatibility? See [this article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2041591) about unsupported hardware configurations. Supported are at least USB 3.0 cards of Intel, TI, AMD and NEC/RENE

Comment: The article indeed confirms my doubt about incompatibility. Unfortunately from the article it's now clear that the Etron USB 3 on my board is not compatible with recommended Intel driver for the VM. Looks like I will have to use USB 2 only.

Answer (score 1):

The VMware Support article
[USB 3.0 support for Windows 7 virtual machine in VMware Workstation and VMware Fusion (2128105)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2128105)
lists the following conditions:

1. The guest VM must be defined with at least VMWare Workstation 12 compatibility
2. In Settings, `USB Controller`, the `USB compatibility` needs to be set to `3.0`.
3. In the virtual machine, download and install the USB3 drivers from the
   [Intel Download Center](http://www.vmware.com/go/dl_intel_usb3_driver).

However, not all hardware configurations are supported.
The most recent VMware article I have managed to find is
[Host and guest OS USB 3.0 and virtual xHCI support with Workstation 9 (2041591)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2041591)
which lists the supported configurations,
and where the Etron USB3 controller is not listed as supported.

Even though the article is for Workstation 9 and not Workstation 12,
this might be taken as an indication that your controller is unsupported,
meaning that you meed to stay with USB2.

Comment: Yes it's clear from that article that despite correctly following all 3 above steps, it's still not working as Etron USB 3.0 chip is unsupported.For now I stay with USB 2.0 only.